# Jolt Transformation with deep nested arrays

Tags: json, jolt

I need to transform a JSON using JOLT. I am a newbie to JOLT transformation. below are the details. We are trying to using Jolt transformation in NiFi to transform jsons.

here is the input

```
   {
  "Parent": {
    "Child": {
      "GrandChild": [
        {
          "DeepDown": [
            {
              "Field2": "2019-01-29T11:32:45",
              "Field1": "015",
              "Field3": "data2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "DeepDown": [
            {
              "Field2": "2019-01-30T11:32:45",
              "Field1": "016",
              "Field3": "data1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the JOLT I wrote (Updated thanks to HariKrishna!)

```
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Parent": {
        "Child": {
          "GrandChild": {
            "*": {
              "DeepDown": {
                "*": {
                  "Field1": "Root.RepeatThis.[].Element1",
                  "Field2": "Root.RepeatThis.[].Element2",
                  "Field3": "Root.RepeatThis.[].Element3"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am expecting the below output.

```
{
  "Root" : {
    "RepeatThis" : [ {
      "Element1" : "015",
      "Element2" : "2019-01-29T11:32:45",
      "Element3" : "data2"
    },  {
      "Element1" : "016",
      "Element2" : "2019-01-30T11:32:45",
      "Element3" : "data1"
    } ]
  }
}
```

I am unable to get the looping working. This is the output i am getting from the JOLT I wrote.

```
{
  "Root" : {
    "RepeatThis" : [ {
      "Element1" : "015"
    }, {
      "Element2" : "2019-01-29T11:32:45"
    }, {
      "Element3" : "data2"
    }, {
      "Element1" : "016"
    }, {
      "Element2" : "2019-01-30T11:32:45"
    }, {
      "Element3" : "data1"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JOLT spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Parent": {
        "Child": {
          "GrandChild": {
            "*": {
              "DeepDown": {
                "*": {
                  "Field2": "Root.RepeatThis.[].Element2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: now i am getting this. it works for one element under DeepDown. If I want to map multiple, it is failing to do so
{
  "Root" : {
    "RepeatThis" : [ {
      "Element1" : "015"
    }, {
      "Element2" : "2019-01-29T11:32:45"
    }, {
      "Element3" : "data2"
    }, {
      "Element1" : "016"
    }, {
      "Element2" : "2019-01-30T11:32:45"
    }, {
      "Element3" : "data1"
    } ]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The following should produce the desired output, `[&3]` will use the array position from GrandChild (going up 3 levels from current context) therefore grouping them correctly:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Parent": {
        "Child": {
          "GrandChild": {
            "*": {
              "DeepDown": {
                "*": {
                  "Field1": "Root.RepeatThis.[&3].Element1",
                  "Field2": "Root.RepeatThis.[&3].Element2",
                  "Field3": "Root.RepeatThis.[&3].Element3"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```